# change in implied volatility with respect to change in spot

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, monte-carlo

It's clear that IV increases as spot decreases, and vice-versa.  In pricing an option, is there any model that is useful in estimating the change in IV with change in spot price?

For example, if the ATM for XYZ is priced today with IV of 0.1, and then tomorrow XYZ drops by 2%, how can I estimate the new ATM's IV?  It certainly wouldn't still be 0.1.

What would be the simplest way to estimate this change?  What would be the most accurate way to estimate it?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that predicting implied vols tomorrow is the same problem as predicting prices tomorrow (since prices and ivs are in 1-to-1 correspondence). Risk Neutral options pricing theory won't help much with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper "Optimal Delta Hedging for Options" [link](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/%7Ehull/DownloadablePublications/Optimal%20Delta%20Hedging.pdf) the author shows that the minimum variance delta is a function of change in implied volatility. If you use equation on page 9 i.e.
$E[\Delta \sigma ]=(\frac{a+b \delta_{bs} + c \delta^2_{bs}}{\sqrt T}) \frac{\Delta S}{S}$ you will get what you want. The parameters a, b, c are fit with OLS regression.